# Table caption appearing in the wrong place

Tags: shiny, dt, caption

I am using DT 0.28 and when I specify the caption argument:

```
    DT::datatable (
      gps$summary[], extension = "Buttons",
      caption = tagList(h1("Caption")),
      options = list(
        autoWidth = TRUE, buttons = c('csv', 'excel'), dom = 'Bfrtip',
        pagingType = "full_numbers", processing = TRUE, scrollX = TRUE,
        stateSave = TRUE),
      selection = list(mode = current_table_selection(), selected = 1, target = 'row'))
  })
```

it appears not above the column headers as shown in [example here (in section 2.7)](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/) but instead the caption is showing up between my column headers and the table data rows!

[image]

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

Strange! This works like this:

```r
datatable(iris, caption = HTML("<h1>hello</h1>"))
```